# Definition of 2D array inside struct in RPC Specification not working

Tags: c, struct, rpc, nfs

I am trying to implements an NFS using RPC. Now my specification file looks something like this: (This is very a basic version of it :) )

```
struct input
{
    char command[20]; 
    char arg[10][10];   
    int numargs;
};

struct lsresult
{
    char arr[50][256];
};

program NFSPROG
{
    version NFSVERSION
    {
        lsresult ls(input) = 1;
        int cd(input) = 2;
        int mkdir(input) = 3;
        int mkfile(input) = 4;
    } = 1;
} = 0x21111111;
```

When I am trying to compile this `Spec.x` using `rpcgen`, I am getting an error like this:

```
 char arg[10][10];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Spec.x, line 4: expected ';'
```

**What may be the reason for this? Can't I declare a 2D array inside a struct in RPC Specification**? (Same error appeared when I tried to declare variables in this way: `int a,b,c` in the struct!)

Comment: But I have not written anything before it...

Comment: It is particularly showing error in that 2D array only...When I am changing it to 1D, error is not coming!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie...is your rpcgen command not showing error for this code?

Comment: [The RPC language](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1671/rpcproto-24229.html) is *similar* to C, but it ***isn't*** C.  Among other things, it does not appear to offer direct support for arrays with more than one dimension.  I'm not well versed in this language myself, so as to be confident enough to write an answer, but it looks like you have some possible alternatives.

Comment: 1. You can probably `typedef` an alias for `char[10]`, and declare an array of 10 of those.

Comment: 2. You may be able to write the needed XDR conversion routines manually, instead of relying on `rpcgen` to write them for you.

Comment: Reading the rpcgen language spec, it seems it doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/6m7rrfn9k/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In termini of rpcgen, you need an array of strings, not a 2d array of chars. First, you have to typedef an argument type

```
typedef string arg<10>;
```

and then make an array of those arguments:

```
struct input
{
    string command<20>;
    arg args[10];
    int numargs;
};
```

similar for lsresult:

```
typedef string filename<50>;

struct lsresult
{
    filename arr[256];
};
```

That should work